# err_connection_timed_out after some successful calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am using http service of AngularJs and it works successfully. But from last three months, I receive err_connection_timed_out after 1 or two successful calls. If I reload the page, then the error disappears.

I am using ASP.Net MVC as backend application and it uses Cookies for session management.

Anybody can help how to resolve this issue?

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Items["dbkey"] = new DBEntities();
}
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var entityContext = HttpContext.Current.Items["dbkey"] as DBEntities;
            if (entityContext != null)
                entityContext.Dispose();
}
```

LoginController

```
public JsonResult JsonLogin(string email, string password)  
{
  // Hashed ticket
  string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);
  cookie.Expires = expiryDate;
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
  HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(mycookie);
}
```

StaffController

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookieName"];         
    if (cookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
    {                
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login/Index");
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

public JsonResult GetData()
{
  var res = entityContext.StaffData.Where(...).ToList();
  return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

Data.js

```
var app = angular.module('StaffApp', []);
app.controller('StaffCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http.get("/Staff/GetData")
            .then(function (response) {
                let data = response.data;
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    angular.forEach(data, function (fm, key) {
                        $scope.Staffs.push(fm);
                    });
                }                
            }, function (response) {                
            });
    };
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your service, otherwise it's not possible to figure anything out from the question description

Comment: The code is added